# Performance of Codility MaxCounter challenge solution

Tags: optimization, performance, algorithm, ruby, programming-challenge

I'm doing some of the Codility challenges using Ruby. The current challenge is "The [MaxCounter](https://codility.com/programmers/lessons/2)," which is described as:

> Calculate the values of counters after applying all alternating operations: increase counter by 1; set value of all counters to current maximum.

See the link above for more details. I managed to get a solution. The performance, however, scored 0, being that some operations timed out. How can I improve my algorithm to perform better?

```
def solution(n, a)
  counter = (0..n-1).to_a.map{|z| z = 0}
  for value in a
    counter.map!{|x| x = counter.max} unless value <= n
    counter[value-1] += 1 unless value == n+1
  end
  counter
end
```

**Update** - my second and third attempts, still fails on performance

2nd

```
def solution(n, a)
  counter = (0..n-1).to_a.map{|z| z = 0}
  a.each{|x| counter.map!{|c| c = counter.max} unless x <= n; counter[x-1] +=1 unless x==n+1;}
  counter
end
```

3rd

```
def solution(n, a)
  counter = (0..n-1).to_a.map{|z| z = 0}
  a.each{|x| counter[x-1] +=1 and next unless x==n+1; counter.map!{|x| x = counter.max};}
  return counter
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't speak to performance, since I don't know what codility considers acceptable, but I'll give it a go.

In terms of reviewing your code, your solutions seem to be getting more and more compact, but that doesn't necessarily help performance. *Shorter code does not  equal faster code.* Sure, if you can *skip* code, that's one thing, but just shaving off bytes of source code is unnecessary.

You certainly should *not* make confusing constructions like `unless ... unless` or `and next unless`. Just read that out loud, and it'll sound strange.

And I don't think there's any advantage to using the `self`-modifying `map!`. In fact, there's no reason to use map at all.

And please don't add pointless semi-colons. A nice aspect of Ruby is *not* having to use those darn things everywhere.

You also seem to misinterpreting how `map` (with or without the `!`) works. These are all equivalent:

```
 counter.map! {|x| x = counter.max}
 counter.map! {|x| counter.max}
 counter.map! {counter.max}
```

In other words, you setting the block parameter `x` does absolutely nothing useful - you don't even *need* the block parameter. The `map` method(s) only use the block's *return value*.

Moreover, your block gets invoked `n` times by `map!`, since `n` is the counter-array's length. That means that `counter.max` gets called `n` times, even though the result is the same each time! If `n` is large, you're looking at a lot of unnecessary work being done there. Worst case is at that *all* of the values in `a` equal `n + 1`, in which case you'll be calling `counter.max` a total of `a.count * n` times. And given that you're using `map!`, I doubt Ruby even has a chance to cache/memoize or otherwise optimize the result of `counter.max`, since you keep changing the array in-place.

Besides, `Array` provides a lot of help here, if you check the docs.

- `fill` does what it says in the name: Fills the array with a given value (or by using a block), which is what you're trying to do with `map!`
- and `Array.new` accepts a length and a seed value, so you can fill a brand new array right away. Don't muck around with mapping a range; just make an array of the right length that's filled with zeros.

Here's my take

```
def solution(n, a)
  counters = Array.new(n, 0) # an array of zeros (and make the var name plural, since it's an array)
  limit = n + 1 # let's just calculate this once, since it's constant

  a.each do |v|
    if v == limit
      counters.fill(counters.max) # max gets called once, and the array gets filled
    elsif v > 0 && v < limit
      counters[v-1] += 1 # just increment
    end
  end

  counters
end
```

It works for the sample input in Codility's example, but as mentioned I haven't gone beyond that.

---

**Update:** With a bit of manual work, you can get rid of the call to `max` entirely by tracking the maximum yourself:

```
def solution(n, a)
  counters = Array.new(n, 0)
  limit = n + 1
  maximum = 0 # the maximum counter value

  a.each do |v|
    if v == limit
      counters.fill(maximum) # use our known maximum
    elsif v > 0 && v < limit
      counter = (counters[v-1] += 1) # increment a counter and store the result
      maximum = counter if counter > maximum # use the new value as maximum, if it's higher
    end
  end

  counters
end
```

This will likely be faster than the first approach, especially for larger values of `n`. It's maybe not quite as Ruby-esque to do things "manually" like this, but it's not terribly complex either.

Comment: Thanks this is much more efficient algorithm according to Codility. It got 40/100 vs my 0, with a complexity of O(N*M). You're explanation for the path was very valuable as well. I appreciate it.

Comment: @AntarrByrd You're welcome. You can probably improve performance further by manually keeping track of the current maximum instead of using `counters.max`. I'll update my answer a little (I can't help myself) :)

Comment: Nice. That got it up to 80/100

Comment: @AntarrByrd Nice - although now I really want to get it  to 100/100. But I don't really have any great ideas, so I'll just let it be, I think :)

Answer (score 0):

Codility 100/100%

https://github.com/mrhead/codility

Credits to MrHead

```
def solution(n, a)
  counters = Array.new(n, 0)
  max = 0
  min = 0

  a.each do |v|
    if v <= n
      if counters[v - 1] < min + 1
        counters[v - 1] = min + 1
      else
        counters[v - 1] += 1
      end
      max = [max, counters[v - 1]].max
    else
      min = max
    end
  end

  counters.each_index do |i|
    counters[i] = min if counters[i] < min
  end
  counters
end
```